# How do I create a disconnect timer in my python discord music bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have tinkered around a discord music bot cog I got from github. I am stuck at trying to create a timer for the bot to leave a voice channel if the /play command hasn't been executed for 5 minutes. The long code is blow or the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/HPqxW2Nk

Commands are removed. The problem is at line 229.
I tried asyncio.sleep(20) but it leaves 20 secs after even if /play has been executed 15 seconds into the timer.

Please help me solve this problem! Thank you very much!

EDIT: is something like this, Patrick?

```
async def on_command_completion(self, ctx):
        futuretime = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
        await asyncio.sleep(300)
        if ctx.invoke(ctx.play):
            pass
        elif datetime.datetime.now() > futuretime:
                await ctx.music_state.stop()



import asyncio
import functools
import logging
import os
import pathlib
import shutil
from asyncio import Queue
import discord
import discord.ext.commands as commands
import youtube_dl
from random import shuffle

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
    #bot.loop.create_task(MusicDelete(bot).background_loop())


def duration_to_str(duration):
    # Extract minutes, hours and days
    minutes, seconds = divmod(duration, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)

    # Create a fancy string
    duration = []
    if days > 0: duration.append(f'**{days}** day(s)')
    if hours > 0: duration.append(f'**{hours}** hr(s)')
    if minutes > 0: duration.append(f'**{minutes}** min(s)')
    if seconds > 0 or len(duration) == 0: duration.append(f'**{seconds}** sec(s)')

    return ', '.join(duration)


class MusicError(commands.UserInputError):
    pass


class Song(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, song_info):
        self.info = song_info.info
        self.requester = song_info.requester
        self.channel = song_info.channel
        self.filename = song_info.filename
        super().__init__(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(self.filename, before_options='-nostdin', options='-vn'))
    def __str__(self):
        return self.info['title']


class SongInfo:
    ytdl_opts = {
        'default_search': 'auto',
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'ignoreerrors': True,
        'source_address': '0.0.0.0', # Make all connections via IPv4
        'nocheckcertificate': True,
        'restrictfilenames': True,
        'logger': logging.getLogger(__name__),
        'logtostderr': False,
        'no_warnings': True,
        'quiet': True,
        'outtmpl': 'C:/Users/MSI/Desktop/GruppBot/musicfiles/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
        'noplaylist': True
    }
    ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_opts)

    def __init__(self, info, requester, channel):
        self.info = info
        self.requester = requester
        self.channel = channel
        self.filename = info.get('_filename', self.ytdl.prepare_filename(self.info))
        self.downloaded = asyncio.Event()
        self.local_file = '_filename' in info

    @classmethod
    async def create(cls, query, requester, channel, loop=None):
        try:
            # Path.is_file() can throw a OSError on syntactically incorrect paths, like urls.
            if pathlib.Path(query).is_file():
                return cls.from_file(query, requester, channel)
        except OSError:
            pass

        return await cls.from_ytdl(query, requester, channel, loop=loop)

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, file, requester, channel):
        path = pathlib.Path(file)
        if not path.exists():
            raise MusicError(f'File {file} not found.')

        info = {
            '_filename': file,
            'title': path.stem,
            'creator': 'local file',
        }
        return cls(info, requester, channel)

    @classmethod
    async def from_ytdl(cls, request, requester, channel, loop=None):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()

        # Get sparse info about our query
        partial = functools.partial(cls.ytdl.extract_info, request, download=False, process=False)
        sparse_info = await loop.run_in_executor(None, partial)

        if sparse_info is None:
            raise MusicError(f'Could not retrieve info from input : {request}')

        # If we get a playlist, select its first valid entry
        if "entries" not in sparse_info:
            info_to_process = sparse_info
        else:
            info_to_process = None
            for entry in sparse_info['entries']:
                if entry is not None:
                    info_to_process = entry
                    break
            if info_to_process is None:
                raise MusicError(f'Could not retrieve info from input : {request}')

        # Process full video info
        url = info_to_process.get('url', info_to_process.get('webpage_url', info_to_process.get('id')))
        partial = functools.partial(cls.ytdl.extract_info, url, download=False)
        processed_info = await loop.run_in_executor(None, partial)

        if processed_info is None:
            raise MusicError(f'Could not retrieve info from input : {request}')

        # Select the first search result if any
        if "entries" not in processed_info:
            info = processed_info
        else:
            info = None
            while info is None:
                try:
                    info = processed_info['entries'].pop(0)
                except IndexError:
                    raise MusicError(f'Could not retrieve info from url : {info_to_process["url"]}')

        return cls(info, requester, channel)

    async def download(self, loop):
        if not pathlib.Path(self.filename).exists():
            partial = functools.partial(self.ytdl.extract_info, self.info['webpage_url'], download=True)
            self.info = await loop.run_in_executor(None, partial)
        self.downloaded.set()

    async def wait_until_downloaded(self):
        await self.downloaded.wait()

    def __str__(self):
        title = f"**{self.info['title']}**"
        creator = f"**{self.info.get('creator') or self.info['uploader']}**"
        duration = f" [ Duration: {duration_to_str(self.info['duration'])} ]" if 'duration' in self.info else ''
        return f'{title} from {creator}{duration}'


class Playlist(asyncio.Queue):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self._queue.__iter__()

    def clear(self):
        for song in self._queue:
            try:
                os.remove(song.filename)
            except:
                pass
        self._queue.clear()

    def get_song(self):
        return self.get_nowait()

    def add_song(self, song):
        self.put_nowait(song)

    def __str__(self):
        info = '__**Queued**__:\n'
        info_len = len(info)
        for song in self:

            s = str(song)
            l = len(s) + 1 # Counting the extra \n
            if info_len + l > 1995:
                info += '[...]'
                break
            info += f'**-** [{s}]({song.info["webpage_url"]})\n'
            info_len += l
        return info


class GuildMusicState:
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.playlist = Playlist(maxsize=10)
        self.voice_client = None
        self.loop = loop
        self.player_volume = 0.5
        self.skips = set()
        self.min_skips = 3
    @property
    def current_song(self):
        return self.voice_client.source

    @property
    def volume(self):
        return self.player_volume

    @volume.setter
    def volume(self, value):
        self.player_volume = value
        if self.voice_client:
            self.voice_client.source.volume = value

    async def stop(self):
        self.playlist.clear()
        if self.voice_client:
            await self.voice_client.disconnect()
            self.voice_client = None

    def is_playing(self):
        return self.voice_client and self.voice_client.is_playing()    

    async def play_next_song(self, song=None, error=None):
        if error:
            await self.current_song.channel.send(f'An error has occurred while playing {self.current_song}: {error}')

        if song and not song.local_file and song.filename not in [s.filename for s in self.playlist]:
            os.remove(song.filename)

        if self.playlist.empty():
            await self.stop()
        else:
            next_song_info = self.playlist.get_song()
            await next_song_info.wait_until_downloaded()
            source = Song(next_song_info)
            source.volume = self.player_volume
            self.voice_client.play(source, after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.play_next_song(next_song_info, e), self.loop).result())
            embed = discord.Embed(color=0x003366)
            embed.set_author(name ="Music", icon_url = 'http://howtodrawdat.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Sebastian-Michaelis-black-butler.png')
            embed.add_field(name="Now Playing:", value=f":notes: [{next_song_info}]({self.current_song.info['webpage_url']})", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Requested by:", value= self.current_song.requester.mention, inline=False)
            #embed.set_thumbnail(url= f"{self.current_song.info['thumbnail']}")
            embed.set_footer(text="Type /playlist to see songs in queue.")
            await next_song_info.channel.send(embed=embed)




class Music:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.music_states = {}

    def __unload(self):
        for state in self.music_states.values():
            self.bot.loop.create_task(state.stop())

    def __local_check(self, ctx):
        if not ctx.guild:
            raise commands.NoPrivateMessage('This command cannot be used in a private message.')
        return True

    async def __before_invoke(self, ctx):
        ctx.music_state = self.get_music_state(ctx.guild.id)

    async def __error(self, ctx, error):
        if not isinstance(error, commands.UserInputError):
            raise error

        try:
            print(error)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            pass # /shrug

    def get_music_state(self, guild_id):
        return self.music_states.setdefault(guild_id, GuildMusicState(self.bot.loop))
```

Comment: Whenever someone uses the `\play` command, compute and store a time 5 minutes in the future.  Then `asyncio.sleep` for 5 minutes.  If someone invokes `\play` again in the interim, overwrite the time.  When each timer wakes up, have it chekc the stored time against the current time and act accordingly.

Comment: How would I store time and overwrite it?

Comment: Either as a global variabel, an attribute of your bot, an attribute of your cog, or in some mapping of servers/channels to times (if your bot is potentially in more than one voice client simultaneously.)

Comment: Is it like `time.clock_settime()`? How do I store time in the future?

Comment: The current time is [`datetime.datetime.now`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) and five minutes from now would be [`datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Comment: Hey, i have posted an edit on top of the code message as it is to big to post here? Is that how I would do it? I don't know how I would make the bot tell if a command is executed

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of one approach to this problem. We keep a global reference to some unique value every time the `play` command is received.  The `play` coroutine will sleep after executing, and then disconnect only if the global value has not changed while it is sleeping.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = Bot('/')

last_play = None

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx):
    global last_play

    # Do the actual work

    obj = object()
    last_play = id(obj)

    await asyncio.sleep(300)

    if last_play == id(obj):
        # disconnect logic

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: I'm very confused as it leaves when audio is being played. The code in line 229 of the pastebin code leaves if playlist queue is 0. if i put an if statement about if not playing() the command runs since the player is downloading the music, leaving silence.